# How to use first-child selector for a certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have several divs and some of them have a class 'test', like the selector first-child only stand out the first DIV that has the 'test' class, however, only works if the class 'test' this in the first div. As I understand it, the selector takes the first object type and not the class really. Does anyone have any ideas? In this example below, I want the div with the "Test 2" stay highlighted by the selector (it is the first DIV having the test class)

```css
.teste:first-child{
 background-color:#F00;
 border:solid 4px #33CCCC; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Teste 1
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 2
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 3
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 4
</div>
```

Comment: You should post this question on Stack Overflow in Portuguese: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Translated using google:::::> Hello, I have several divs and some of them have a
class 'test', like the selector first-child only stand out
the first DIV that has the 'test' class, however, only
works if the class 'test' this in the first div. As I
understand it, the selector takes the first object type
and not the class really. Does anyone have any ideas?
In this example below, I want the div with the "Test 2"
stay highlighted by the selector (it is the first DIV
having the test class).

Comment: @AnilPanwar, and you will translate the answers back to portuguese for him?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar: `div:first-of-type`

```
div:first-of-type { background-color:#F00;
    border:solid 4px #33CCCC;    }
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jbhyo64b/2/)

y si quieres el siguiente es:

```
.teste:nth-child(2) { background-color: green }
```

Me imagino que es este el que quieres.

So in English I assume he's looking for the first "teste" class to have a styling which means he needs `.teste:nth-child(2)`. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `:not(.teste) + .teste` after the first line like below:

```
/* If element is first to it's parent and has class "red", it shall get border. */
.teste:first-child,
/* If ".red" element is not first to its parent, but is immediately following an element without class ".red", it shall also deserve the honor of said border. */
:not(.teste) + .teste {
    background-color: #f00;
    border: 4px solid #3cc;
}
```

Alternatively you can contemplate using js.